# What is the Sweelinck fantasia played by Glenn Gould?

Tags: history, classical-music

Glenn Gould has [a CD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000028NB) of early music in which he plays a piece by Jan Sweelinck simply titled "Fantasia in D." I have searched hard for this piece - it is not one of the other Sweelinck fantasias like the one in D minor, the ones in Dorian, etc. There are two recordings on youtube of Gould playing this, and I found one amateur recording as well - so the piece must exist somewhere.

Can anyone help me identify this piece, ideally by catalog number? I would be most grateful of all if anyone knew where to find free (or available for purchase) sheet music for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in Volume II of the Fitzwilliam Virginal Book, titled "Fantasia 4." But given the circumstances surrounding the compilation of the FVB (it was made by a not-especially-competent amateur musician copying manuscripts loaned by his friends to help while away the time while he was in prison) history does not record the significance of the number "4" in the title.

See page 297 of http://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/178083.